# How to use virtual-repeater.for with a Map

Tags: aurelia

I'm trying to use the aurelia-ui-virtualization to create a repeater with a infinite scroll use a Map

I looked in to the documentation and wasn't able to find a sample that uses Map, only Arrays
The template:

```
<template>
<div virtual-repeat.for="[key,valu] of mp">
${key}

</div>

</template>
```

And the class:

```
export class App{
   mp= new Map<any,any>([['one','foo'],['two','bar]])
}
```

I was expecting that the repeater worket but I'm getting:

```
aurelia-ui-virtualization.js?b7bb:791 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Value is not iterateable for virtual repeat.
at VirtualRepeat.itemsChanged (aurelia-ui-virtualization.js?b7bb:791)
at VirtualRepeat.attached (aurelia-ui-virtualization.js?b7bb:727)
at Controller.attached (aurelia-templating.js?8628:3759)
at View.attached (aurelia-templating.js?8628:1772)
at ViewSlot.attached (aurelia-templating.js?8628:2130)
at View.attached (aurelia-templating.js?8628:1777)
at ViewSlot.attached (aurelia-templating.js?8628:2130)
at View.attached (aurelia-templating.js?8628:1777)
at ViewSlot.attached (aurelia-templating.js?8628:2130)
at eval (aurelia-framework.js?0682:115)
```

Comment: I'd add the entries() function to the binding expression:
<template>
<div virtual-repeat.for="[key,value] of mp.entries()">

Comment: Tried .entries() and I still get the same error

Answer (score 3):

I asked this same question on aurelia discuss [link](https://gitter.im/aurelia/Discuss) and @bigopon told me it's not yet supported.

So I end up using a value converter

```
export class MapArrayValueConverter {
  toView(value) {
    if(value){
      if(value instanceof Map )
      return [...value]
    }
  }

  fromView(value) {

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From my testing, it doesn't appear the virtual-repeater is capable of directly using a Map.

Try this.

```
<template>
  <div virtual-repeat.for="item of mp">
    ${item};${item[0]};${item[1]}
  </div>
</template>
```

and

```
export class App {
    map = new Map([["one", "foo"], ["two", "bar"]]);
    mp = Array.from(map);
}
```

Comment: I tested too and I couldn't make it work using Maps, but from the documentation page they said it would work "When dealing with large collections of items (thousands, upwards of tens of thousands), whether that be an array or map" from [link](https://aurelia.io/docs/plugins/virtualization#introduction). I appreciate your answer @YardGnomeNinja, but I really would like to use Maps

Comment: I upvoted your answer but I end up using a Value Converter